# Selenium: Is possible to get the text between two xpath selections?

Tags: python, regex, xpath, selenium

I have:

```
<center><h3>Title</h3></center>
...
stuff here that I want selected in <p>...</p>elements
...
<a href="index.htm">Content</a>
```

The first and the last I can find them with xpath: `//center/h3` and respectively `//a[@href="index.html"]`.

Can I take the area between this two xpath selections and if yes how, or should I use regular expressions on the source code of that page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [this link](http://poeticcode.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/xpath-what-about-the-between-operator/), a method for selecting between two xpaths using `following`.

This is the working code:

```
//p[preceding::center/h3 and following::a[@href="index.htm"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `//a[@href="index.html"]/../p`